# Show that $\int_Ax^2\mu_X(dx)\le\frac{12}{11u^2}\{1-\Re(\Phi_X(u))\}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, estimation

> Let $A=[-\frac1u,\frac1u]$, Show that $$\displaystyle\int_Ax^2\mu_X(dx)\le\frac{12}{11u^2}\{1-\Re(\Phi_X(u))\}$$
>
> where $\Phi_X(u)$ is the characteristic function of the r.v. $X$
>
> **Hint:** $1-\cos(x)\ge0$  and $1-\cos(x)\ge\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}$

$\displaystyle\{1-\Re(\Phi_X(u))\}=1-\Re\bigg(\int e^{iux}\mu_X(dx)\bigg)=1-\int\cos\langle u,x\rangle\mu_X(dx)$
$\displaystyle=\int 1-\cos\langle u,x\rangle\mu_X(dx)\ge\int_{|x|\le\frac{\sqrt{12}}{u}}\frac{u^2x^2}{2}-\frac{u^4x^4}{24}\mu_X(dx)$

(because  $1-\cos(x)\ge0$ and therefore we need only the positive part of $\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}$, which is in $\{|x|\le\frac{\sqrt{12}}{u}\}$)

Now I have to estimate correctly, but I don't see how, I tried to separate the integral, for the first I took the domain $\{|x|\le\frac{1}{u}\}$, which gave an integral greater than $\int_{\{|x|\le\frac{1}{u}\}}\frac{x^2}{2}$, but I couldn't manage to do an estimation for the second one, for the domain $\{\frac{1}{u}\le|x|\le\frac{\sqrt{12}}{u}\}$)

Change of variable also failed, I even don't know if it's allowed to replace $x$  without changing $\mu_X(dx)$

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is $\mathcal{R}$ the real part?

Comment: @Alex yes it is.

Comment: I'm curious, what's $\mathcal{Im}( \Phi(\cdot))$ then?

Comment: @Alex $\int e^{iux}\mu_X=\int\cos(ux)\mu_X+i\int\sin(ux)\mu_X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the pieces are there, this is only a matter of using them in the right order. Note first that
$$
1-\Re\varphi_X(u)=\Re(1-\varphi_X(u))=\int_\mathbb R(1-\cos(ux))\mu_X(\mathrm dx),
$$
hence
$$
1-\Re\varphi_X(u)\geqslant\int_A(1-\cos(ux))\mu_X(\mathrm dx),
$$
because $1-\cos$ is nonnegative everywhere. Next, note that, for every $|t|\leqslant1$,
$$
1-\cos(t)\geqslant\frac12t^2-\frac1{24}t^4\geqslant\frac{11}{24}t^2,
$$
because $t^4\leqslant t^2$ when $|t|\leqslant1$, hence the second inequality provided for $1-\cos$ yields, for every $x$ in $A$,
$$
1-\cos(ux)\geqslant\frac{11}{24}u^2x^2,
$$
which implies
$$
\int_A(1-\cos(ux))\mu_X(\mathrm dx)\geqslant\frac{11}{24}u^2\int_Ax^2\mu_X(\mathrm dx).
$$
This proves that

> $$
> \int_Ax^2\mu_X(\mathrm dx)\leqslant\frac{24}{11u^2}(1-\Re\varphi_X(u)).
> $$

Note that a limited expansion of $\varphi_X(u)$ when $u\to0$ shows that every factor smaller than $2$ (such as your $\frac{12}{11}$) is impossible if $\varphi_X$ is defined as
$$
\varphi_X(u)=E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm iuX}].
$$
Assume for example that $X=\pm1$ with equal probability, then, for every $|u|\leqslant1$,
$$
\int_Ax^2\mu_X(\mathrm dx)=1,
$$
while
$$
\varphi_X(u)=\cos u,
$$
hence, when $u\to0$,
$$
\frac1{u^2}(1-\Re\varphi_X(u))=\frac1{u^2}(1-\cos u)\to\frac12.
$$

Comment: I think, you have a mistake $\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t^4}{24}\ge\frac{11}{\textbf{24}}t^2$ or not ?

Comment: Ab. so. lu. te. ly. Thanks. But I have some doubts about your 12/11...

Comment: see here I have a newer version of the book and it is still the same http://bookre.org/reader?file=1515803&pg=133

Comment: OK. You might want to understand why the argument I give at the end shows that every constant $\lt2$ is **impossible**.

Comment: Yes, please. I'm interested.

Comment: You were supposed to put your brain in the position ON, since this was explained in my answer. Now I added an explicit counterexample (but I shouldn't have).

Comment: your edited text didn't appear 5 min ago, strange. but at least it is clear now thanks a lot.

Comment: Once again, the edited text with a full counterexample should not have been necessary to put your brain in motion...